# How can I subtract hours from a variable being used in a Linux "at" command?

Tags: shell-script, date

I am using variables to state the start time and date for an `at` job.  This works fine, but now I realize I need to subtract a number of hours from the time variable to make the at job run earlier than is stated in the variable (this variable is used elsewhere in the script as well as for the at job)

```
#variables
time=2:00pm
date=2018-1-16

#I need to subtract 4 hours from the time variable 
at -f /home/JS/filename $time-4hours $date >attemp 2>&1
```

I thought about introducing a 3rd variable as the result of the subtraction but can't get that going either.

Comment: you need to quote the time/date argument.  without quotes, it's two arguments, not one.   try `at -f /home/JS/filename "$time -4 hours $date" >attemp 2>&1`

Comment: 12hours-based timestamps will be more complicated to handle than 24hours-one. Can you at least change that or not at all? Are you guaranteed that the delta of 4 hours will not let you roll back to previous day?

Comment: On 24hours arithmetic and depending on your platform (should be ok on any GNU based ones), this could work: `time=1400 ; date --date="$time -4 hours" +%H%M` which outputs `1000`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek `at` has pretty sophisticated date/time parsing.    IIRC, it was doing things like `now + 2 hours` and `4pm tomorrow` long before GNU `date` added that capability.  I doubt if it's going to be confused by a 12 hour clock, as long as the am/pm indicator is included.

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian system:

```
$ echo true | at 2:00pm 2018-01-18 - 4 hours
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 10 at Thu Jan 18 10:00:00 2018
```

So, given appropriate values in `time` and `date`, I think this should work:

```
$ at -f ... $time $date - 4 hours
```

---

It's a bit picky about the order of the tokens, it seems they need to be in order *time*, *date*, *delta*. E.g. this doesn't work:

```
$ echo true | at 2:00pm - 4 hours 2018-01-18
syntax error. Last token seen: 2018-01-18
Garbled time
```